# I cant access from host machine to virtual machine webserver domain in Debian 11

Tags: http, firefox, debian, apache2, virtualbox

I have installed an apache server on a debian 11 on a virtualbox machine.

I have set the static ip to 192.168.1.69, I have added access rules to the firewall to let traffic through on port 80.

I can see the default debian webpage if I go to the windows browser and go to 192.168.1.69, I have even configured it to install webmin on 192.168.1.69:10000, which works on firefox in the host machine, and I can access it from the windows powershell in the host machine by sshing to 192.168.1.69.

I created a server at /var/www/tests.dev with a /public directory with an index.html inside with a "You made it"

I have made
`chown -R www-data /var/www/tests.dev`

This is the virtual server configuration:

```
ServerName tests.dev
ServerAdmin webmaster@tests.dev
ServerAlias www.tests.dev
DocumentRoot /var/www/tests.dev/public
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access-tests.dev.log "combined".
```

I have placed in the windows hosts of the host machine the line
192.168.1.69 tests.dev

If I ping from windows powershell to tests.dev it works, if I ssh user@tests.dev it works and I can log in.

But when I do it in firefox, in the host machine, if i go to http://tests.dev there is no way, the only thing I get is "the connection has expired", I don't know what I can try anymore, I have tried everything.

But... and this is the interesing thing... if i do a wget http://tests.dev in powershell I get

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : <html>
                    <h1>You made it</h1>
                    </html>

RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
                    Connection: Keep-Alive
                    Accept-Ranges: bytes
                    Content-Length: 36
                    Content-Type: text/html
                    Date: Fri, 27 Jan 2023 14:49:00 GMT
                    ETag: "24-5f33de871d523...
Forms             : {}
Headers           : {[Keep-Alive, timeout=5, max=100], [Connection, Keep-Alive], [Accept-Ranges, bytes],
                    [Content-Length, 36]...}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
RawContentLength  : 36
```

Can anyone help me why cant access on firefox on tests.dev on my host machine? Thank you.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem as i was figuring out when i writing the question, is firefox, doesnt allow http requests, i downloaded seamonkey and tried "http://tests.dev" now i see the page with the "you made it"